# In my listener how to check if dryrun flag is set or not

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a listner which updates test result to test management tool at `end_test`. The problem is when run in `dryrun` mode it update every thing as `Passed` which is False result.

Is there a way I can access `ROBOT_OPTIONS` in my listener because it will have all the command line options, OR is there an alternative way of checked if `-dryrun` is enabled in my listener library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing that is officially supported. Though, a solution that might work for you is to import `sys`, and then scan `sys.argv` for the `--dryrun` option. This won't work if you have the dry run argument inside an argument file.

Another simple solution is for you to define a variable when you specify the dry run flag (eg: `robot --dryrun --variable DRYRUN:True`), and then your logic can use that variable.